# Formato de texto a cuerpo de mensaje

Tags: excel, vba, macros

estoy realizando una macro en Excel la cual sirve para enviar una reunión con Outlook, todo funciona bien pero en el cuerpo del mensaje quiero que el texto tenga formato, por ejemplo poner el texto de colores, con negrita, etc. Cosa que aun no he logrado, les comparto mi código para que puedan ayudarme.

```
Sub EnvioConvocatoriaT()
Dim ol As New Outlook.Application
Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
Dim itmApoint As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set itmApoint = ol.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

With itmApoint
.Start = DateSerial(2017, 8, 11) + TimeSerial(14, 0, 0)
.End = DateSerial(2017, 8, 11) + TimeSerial(16, 0, 0)
.Subject = "Correo de prueba"
.Body = "Este es un correo de prueba"
.Importance = olImportanceNormal
.Recipients.Add ("correodeprueba@gmail.com")
.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
.Location = "Local Lima - 01"
.ReminderSet = True
.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 5
.Save
'.Send
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que has buscado/investigado acerca de dar formato al contenido de un mensaje de Outlook?. Referencia [ask]

Answer (score 1):

En el caso de un `olAppointmentItem` la única forma de escribir un Body con formato es usando la propiedad [`RTFBody`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/meetingitem-rtfbody-property-outlook), para lo cual deberías escribir el mensaje con código [`RTF`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) (Rich text format)

Por ejemplo:

```
RtfText = "{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;}{\fonttbl
{\f0\fswiss\fcharset1252 Times New Roman;}
}{\*\generator CuteEditor 5.0;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\cf1\f0\fs24\qj\b0\i0\ulnone Hola \cf1\f0\fs24\qj\b1\i0\ulnone Mundo\cf1\f0\fs24\qj\b0\i0\ulnone !}"
itmApoint.RTFBody = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(RtfText);
```

Como `RTFBody` espera un array de bytes, es necesario convertir el código `RTF` en un array mediante: `Encoding.Default.GetBytes()`, El formato [`RTF`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) no es muy cómodo de escribir, pero eventualmente puedes salvar desde Word a un archivo [`RTF`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) y ver de adaptarlo para incorporar a `RTFBody`